# wordpress category rewrite rule with pagination

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

with the help of someone here I was able to filter two or more categories via this rewrite rule

```
'^combine/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?category_name=$matches[1]+$matches[2]+$matches[3]', 'top'
```

so if I access

```
/combine/michelin/tires/cars/
```

I can filter posts in the category 'cars' that also have 'tires' as a category that also have 'michelin' as a category.

Problem is when I try to use pagination. I have this rewrite rule( put before the other rule)

```
 '^combine/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]{1,}/?$','index.php?category_name=$matches[1]+$matches[2]+$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]', 'top'
```

and when i access this page it gives me not-found
/combine/michelin/tires/cars/page/2/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it doing these rewrites in the following order.

So I specified 3 category url in the beginning
then 2 category url below that
and in the and
single category url

```
/combine/brand/category1/category2/page/1-9/
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^combine/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]*)$/','index.php?category_name=$matches[1]+$matches[2]+$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]', 'top'
);

/combine/brand/category1/page/1-9
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^combine/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]*)$','index.php?category_name=$matches[1]+$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top'
);

/combine/brand/category1/
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^combine/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?category_name=$matches[1]+$matches[2]+$matches[3]', 'top'
);
```